# Subdirectories "." and ".." | PHP

Tags: php, directory

Why does PHP output two subdirectories that has: `.` and `..` when reading a directory.

From PHP.net:

```
<?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Outputs:

```
filename: . : filetype: dir
filename: .. : filetype: dir
filename: apache : filetype: dir
filename: cgi : filetype: dir
filename: cli : filetype: dir
```

Why does it do that?

Comment: it's normal thing in *nix world

Comment: You may want to look into [`DirectoryIterator`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) instead of `readdir`...  It even has a method `$file->isDot()` to detect this very thing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because "." and ".." are actual directories (in the *nix world).

"." refers to the current directory
".." refers to the parent directory.

If you do an "ls" you'll see the same exact output.

Comment: Ah, I see... explains it, I was wondering if they were hidden, hidden folders that no one may be able to see :P Thanks.

Comment: Hidden directories start with "." but contain other characters.  For example ".mozilla" and ".emacs"

Answer (score 2):

`.` and `..` are symlinks to the current and parent directory and they are present in most file systems, so if you don't want these to show in the dir listing in your code, try this:

```
$skipped = array('.', '..'); 
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
   if(in_array($file, $skipped)) continue;
   echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
}
closedir($dh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `glob()` instead if you don't need the `.` and `..` entries.

Comment: *(tipp)* [PHPArchitect Bill Karwin putting glob to the test](http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/28/putting-glob-to-the-test)